# Naming the output of convert command and piping it to mail

Tags: pipe, email

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% -resize 35% 189_0538.JPG - | uuencode - img.jpg | mail -s "Some Picture" someid@somemail.com
```

The output of convert (Image Magick) should be named (file name) and it should be sent as a normal picture mail attachment. The above command does not work.

EDIT1:
The error that I get when I run the above command is:

```
uuencode: fopen-ing -: Unknown system error
```

Comment: Did you read uuencode's man page? There's an example in there.

Answer (score 1):

I use `sendemail` to be able to easily append a file to an email from the command line. Notice the ***e*** in sendEmail

```
sendemail -f ADDRESS -t ADDRESS -u SUBJECT \
-a <( convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% -resize 35% 189_0538.JPG - )
```

The <( ... ) construction automatically creates a temporary filehandle so a regular file is not required (pretty much as you do with your pipe).